# Unable to trigger change event when dropdown is autoselected in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, events, dropdown

In my code below, onColorChanged is not triggered when the selection gets updated programatically. It does trigger when I go to UI and select the color from the dropdown. Not sure what is going on.

```
          <div class="card border-0">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <label for="color">
                            <b>Color</b>
                    </label>
                    <select class="form-control" ng-init=null id="colorList" aria-describedby="colorList" *ngIf="myColorList$"
                        [(ngModel)]="selectedColor" (change)="onColorChanged(selectedColor)">
                        <option *ngFor="let c of myColorList$ | async" [ngValue]="c">{{c}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Trigger the onchange event manually inside the code that changed the selected option. Change events are only triggered automatically when the user actually clicks and selects the element, not when JS code mimics the same.

Comment: For that you need to subscribe to the `valueChanges` observable property of the FormControl . `onColorChanged` won't trigger programmatically.

Comment: Can you show the code that updates the `selectedColor` variable? If the `selectedColor` value does not match any of the values in `myColorList$` - the onChange event does not get called.

Comment: @Niladri Does  `valueChanges` work on template driven forms? I am not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass name attribute to the select tag.
Cover select tag in form element.

```
    <form name="colorForm">

        <select class="form-control" id="colorList" name="myColor" [(ngModel)]="selectedColor" (change)="onColorChanged(selectedColor)"> 
<option *ngFor="let c of myColorList$ | async" [ngValue]="c">{{c}}</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

Comment: can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you have to call `onColorChanged()` programatically.

Like:

```
this.selectedColor = 'red';
this.onColorChanged(this.selectedColor);
```